# adjective vs adverb for a gerund

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, gerunds, participles

This sentence occurs in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voting#Meetings_and_gatherings):

> The method of voting can range from formal submission of written votes, through show of hands, voice voting or audience response systems, to informal noting which outcome seems to be preferred by more people.

*informal* is a recent change from *informally*, and I find myself torn over changing it back.  *noting* here is a gerund (a quasi-noun) rather than a participle (a kind of adjective); and so it seems formally to require an adjective rather than an adverb.  And yet …

> I monitor the cat's health by, among other things, occasionally observing how much water is in his bowl.

… here, *occasional observing* would feel very wrong.

What do you think?

Comment: I note informally that “to noting informal” would be more clearly wrong, but why?

Comment: *Informal* is correct; it parallels *formal*. It’s just that there’s an *of* missing: *from formal submission of notes... to informal noting **of** which outcome seems to be preferred...*

Answer (score 4):

"Informally" is correct, as your example with "occasionally observing" shows. Here "noting" is a gerund, not a verbal noun. Whereas verbal nouns are modified by adjectives, gerunds are modified by adverbs.

Compare [this example from Wikipedia:](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbal_noun)

> 1. The **rapid** erasing **of** the tape saved our bacon. (Verbal noun)
> 2. **Rapidly** erasing the tape saved our bacon. (Gerund)

Comment: *Informal* is correct. It’s *from formal submission to informal noting*. If it were *informally*, it would read *from formally submitting to informally noting*. Granted there’s an *of* missing after *noting* though.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Putting the "of" after "noting" would turn "noting" into a verbal noun, making the adjective "informal" correct. But without that "of," it's a gerund.

Comment: Yes, errors of omission can do that to a word.